# Empty desktop after installing xrdp on Centos 6.5 with XFCE as window manager

Tags: centos, xfce, remote-desktop

I followed the directions to install xRDP from this site (http://ajmatson.net/wordpress/2014/01/install-xrdp-remote-desktop-to-centos-6-5/)

When I RDP from Windows -> Linux, I successfully enter username/password, but then I get an empty desktop.  It shows the desktop wallpaper (not actually my wallpaper either -- looks like the default wallpaper for XFCE/CentOS)

I'm not sure what I should be seeing at this point.  It doesn't matter if I am already logged in interactively or not. (BTW -- Should I be seeing a new desktop or the same one that I'm logged in with? I imagine that is configurable anyhow.)

**UPDATE:**

I confirmed that I am indeed seeing Gnome (The `gnome-session` command is running) when I login to XRDP instead of `startxfce4`.  [From some searching around](http://bugs.centos.org/bug_revision_view_page.php?rev_id=293), this may be realated to to be a bug in Centos 6.5 wherein CentOS had some code changed that normally would have read from the user's `.xsession` or `.Xclients` file.  However, I compared the 6.4 and the 6.5 file and I'm not seeing a difference.

Furthermore, this doesn't entirely explain everything.  It's probably OK if Gnome runs instead of XFCE, but why no panels, menus, can't right click, etc?

I experimented with making adjustments to files like the `startwm.sh` file and the scripts in `xinit`. This yielded some fruit -- I was able to see a new XFCE desktop, but the adjustments I made seem to be incomplete because the .bashrc file and related scripts failed to execute and it feels hacky.

Answer (score 0):

When using XRDP you'll typically see a new desktop. If you want to see your existing desktop you'll need to reconfigure things via the configuration files provided by XRDP or use VNC.